# Upload Bitmap in a Stream using WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, bitmap, stream

I am trying to upload images captured from my WebCam to a WCF Service.

I have the whole service that works bug free - tested with images/files on my HD. The problem is, that the image from the webcam is saved in a BitMap (C#).

The service takes Stream as input parameter. When I use

```
image.Save(mystream,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
client.SendFile(mystream);
```

A 0 byte stream is uploaded.

How do I get this working?

Thanks.

Comment: yes. mystream is initialized as a MemoryStream. It gets filled with image, but that takes time until then client.SendFile is executed hence uploading a 0 byte stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you must seek back to the beginning after saving the image to the stream using `mystream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)`, because the current position in the stream is just after the last written byte.

Comment: Solved!! I should have thought of this before. Thanks alot!